# What is the mean of zendframework suggests installing

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php, dependency-management

I install Zend Skeleton application from [this link](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/archive/release-2.2.7.zip), then install via Composer. Composer notice:

```
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ext-intl (ext/intl for i18n features (included in default builds of PHP))
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing doctrine/annotations (Doctrine Annotations >=1.0 for annotation features)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib (Fallback random byte generator for Zend\Math\Rand if OpenSSL/Mcrypt extensions are unavail
able)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing ocramius/proxy-manager (ProxyManager to handle lazy initialization of services)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendpdf (ZendPdf for creating PDF representations of barcodes)
zendframework/zendframework suggests installing zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha (ZendService\ReCaptcha for rendering ReCaptchas in Zend\Captcha and/or Zend\Form)
```

[image]

Please explain for me about above notice (It says that `suggests installing`). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use some optional features, you have to install one of these packages as well.

It's some kind of advertising other packages that may make sense to use, but are not necessarily needed.

Note that in Zend Framework 2, even though Composer is being used, some packages really need those suggestions installed if you don't use the `zendframework/zendframework` main package - the developers are in the process of better modularizing the packages.

Comment: Can you help me some JSON lines to install suggested dependencies: `ext-intl`, `doctrine/annotations`, `ircmaxell/random-lib`, `ocramius/proxy-manager`, `zendframework/zendpdf` and `zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha`?

Comment: ext-intl is a PHP extension - this cannot be installed with Composer, but either needs activation in the `php.ini` file, or installing it if not present. The rest are Composer packages, and if you decide you need them: `composer require thepackage/name` on the command line installs them.